# Get name of the current template file

Tags: templates

I've found this to display the current name of the file used in template:

```
function get_template_name () {
    foreach ( debug_backtrace() as $called_file ) {
        foreach ( $called_file as $index ) {
            if ( !is_array($index[0]) AND strstr($index[0],'/themes/') AND !strstr($index[0],'footer.php') ) {
                $template_file = $index[0] ;
            }
        }
    }
    $template_contents = file_get_contents($template_file) ;
    preg_match_all("Template Name:(.*)\n)siU",$template_contents,$template_name);
    $template_name = trim($template_name[1][0]);
    if ( !$template_name ) { $template_name = '(default)' ; }
    $template_file = array_pop(explode('/themes/', basename($template_file)));
    return $template_file . ' > '. $template_name ;
}
```

Source: [get name of page template on a page](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-name-of-page-template-on-a-page)

It works quite well, except that in the backend, in the template select box, I get this ugly extra entry:

[image: screenshot]

Does anybody have any idea how to fix it? I don't even know why this function is called in the backend. Is there a conditional function like `is_frontend()` - maybe this would solve the problem?

Comment: @chodorowicz - While I will stop one step short of calling the selection of `functions.php` as a bug, I will agree completely with your premise. To make matters worse I scanned the WordPress core code and found about 5 places where there could have been a hook to allow you to handle this issue yet I found none. I'd suggest posting a ticket on http://core.trac.wordpress.org.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - thanks for comment, but doesn't `template_include` hook, which t31os suggested, solve the issue? Or maybe I've misunderstood you.

Comment: @chodorowicz - You now have me very confused. The answer @t31os gave solves a problem that is very different from the one that I understood you were asking based on your question and your follow up comments to other's answers. But if @t31os' answer solved your actual need, then my confusion here is unimportant as your question has been answered.

Comment: Yes, the actual need was to display the name of the currently used theme file, the code I posted had a flaw (which can be solved by moving the function out of the main theme folder), but @t31os' solution is much cleaner and fulfills the need, but, if I understand you correctly, the real problem (WP shouldn't try to read `functions.php` as page template file) still persists. I'll try to post it on trac, haven't done it yet. Greetings!

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - it already has a patch :) http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16689

Comment: @chodorowicz - Yes, my comment was addressing the real problem, keeping WP from trying to read `functions.php` and/or allowing you to write a hook to change was is returned. Glad to see you found a patch rather than duplicate it; it's so hard to find those existing tickets.

Comment: I've made a new plugin in order to display the current template. Check it on http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/display-template-name/

Comment: ^ ie. you took the code from my answer and wrapped it into a plugin. And you did all that without providing any credit to the origin, neither myself or the WP stackexchange... nice... :/

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/253820/how-to-use-if-is-page-template

Answer (score 46, accepted):

apparently this is enough:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'show_template');
function show_template() {
    global $template;
    echo basename($template);
}
```

or just use it directly in template (I tend to echo in footer.php in HTML comment)

```
<?php global $template; echo basename($template); ?>
```

Comment: That won't work with get-template-part just so you know, it only shows single.php (for example) and not the file it is in.

Comment: Yes, it's true. To get the name of included file you'd probably need to use something like this `echo __FILE__;`

Comment: this is fine, for example in cases when you modify the default template without assigning it to a post in backoffice. For example using custom routes and the template_include filter. Thank you.

Comment: How could I do this within a loop? I'm trying to output the URL to one page of each template file.

Comment: @JacobTheDev maybe using `echo __FILE__` - because this won't work, it displays only main, initial template

Answer (score 80):

You could set a global variable during the `template_include` filter and then later check that global vairable to see which template has been included.

You naturally wouldn't want the complete path along with the file, so i'd recommend truncating down to the filename using PHP's `basename` function.

**Example code:**
Two functions, one to set the global, one to call upon it.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'var_template_include', 1000 );
function var_template_include( $t ){
    $GLOBALS['current_theme_template'] = basename($t);
    return $t;
}

function get_current_template( $echo = false ) {
    if( !isset( $GLOBALS['current_theme_template'] ) )
        return false;
    if( $echo )
        echo $GLOBALS['current_theme_template'];
    else
        return $GLOBALS['current_theme_template'];
}
```

You can then call upon `get_current_template` wherever you need it in the theme files, noting this naturally needs to occur after the `template_include` action has fired(you won't need to worry about this if the call is made inside a template file).

For page templates there is `is_page_template()`, bearing in mind that will only help in the case of page templates(a far less *catch all* function).

**Information on functions used or referenced above:**

- [is_page_template()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template)
- [add_filter()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter)
- [basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

Comment: Awesome! I knew there had to be a simpler way.

Comment: One to add to the top of my debugging functions list.

Comment: People may also be interested in the built-in `is_single`, `is_attachment`, `is_singular`, `is_page` and the other [`is_...` functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference).

Answer (score 18):

Between native WP functions like [get_template_part()](http://queryposts.com/function/get_template_part/) and PHP's native includes the most reliable way to see theme's files used is to fetch list of all included files and filter out whatever doesn't belong to theme (or themes when parent and child combination is used):

```
$included_files = get_included_files();
$stylesheet_dir = str_replace( '\\', '/', get_stylesheet_directory() );
$template_dir   = str_replace( '\\', '/', get_template_directory() );

foreach ( $included_files as $key => $path ) {

    $path   = str_replace( '\\', '/', $path );

    if ( false === strpos( $path, $stylesheet_dir ) && false === strpos( $path, $template_dir ) )
        unset( $included_files[$key] );
}

var_dump( $included_files );
```

Answer (score 12):

*An addition (more sweet code) to other answers here.*

### Template Name

To just get the current **page template** name, use the following line.

```
is_page() AND print get_page_template_slug( get_queried_object_id() );
```

### File Name

When you just want to echo the **current template file name**, go with the following

**Edit:** Here's the new version of the plugin wrapped up in a class. It shows both the current template file name, as well as the template hierarchy file name in the shutdown hook at the most bottom of the page.

What the plugin tells you:

- Is the template from the parent of child/current theme?
- Is the template served from a subfolder? If yes: Tells you the name
- The template file name.

Just copy the following code into a file and name it `wpse10537_template_info.php`, upload it to your plugins directory and activate it.

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: (#10537) »kaiser« Get Template file name */

if ( ! class_exists( 'wpse10537_template_name' ) )
{
    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'wpse10537_template_name', 'init' ) );

class wpse10537_template_name
{
    protected static $instance;

    public $stack;

    public static function init()
    {
        is_null( self :: $instance ) AND self :: $instance = new self;
        return self :: $instance;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        if ( is_admin() )
            return;

        add_action( 'wp', array( $this, 'is_parent_template' ), 0 );
        add_action( 'wp', array( $this, 'get_template_file' ) );
        add_action( 'template_include', array( $this, 'get_template_name' ) );
        add_action( 'shutdown', array( $this, 'get_template_name' ) );
    }

    public function get_template_name( $file )
    {
        if ( 'template_include' === current_filter() )
        {
            $this->to_stack(
                 "Template file"
                ,basename( $file )
            );
            return $file;
        }

        // Return static var on echo call outside of filter
        if (
            current_user_can( 'manage_options' )
            AND defined( 'WP_DEBUG' )
            AND WP_DEBUG 
        )
            return print implode( " &ndash; ", $this->stack );
    }

    public function get_template_file()
    {
        if ( ! is_post_type_hierarchical( get_post_type() ) )
            return;

        $slug = get_page_template_slug( get_queried_object_id() );
        if ( ! strstr( $slug, "/" ) )
            return $this->to_stack( "Template", $slug );

        $this->to_stack(
             "Subdirectory"
            ,strstr( $slug, "/", true )
        );

        $this->to_stack(
             "Template (in subdirectory)"
            ,str_replace( "/", "", strstr( $slug, "/" ) )
        );
    }

    public function is_parent_template()
    {
        if ( ! is_null( wp_get_theme()->parent ) )
            return $this->to_stack( 'from parent theme' );

        $this->to_stack( 'from current/child theme' );
    }

    public function to_stack( $part, $item = '' )
    {
        $this->stack[] = "{$part}: {$item}";
    }
} // END Class wpse10537_template_name

} // endif;
```

<sup>*This plugin can run as MU-Plugin too.*</sup>

You can then simply call `wpse10537_get_template_name()` at any point (in for example a theme template). This avoids cluttering the global namespace.

Comment: `template_redirect` is not passing anything, I think you are confusing with `template_include`. Also I'd check if inside the filter instead of if static var filled. If some code decides to run hook additional time it can wreck things.

Comment: @Rarst Done/Fixed. Thanks for the hint and pointing out the filter name.

Answer (score 7):

The template name is stored in the postmeta table, so all you need to do is put this somewhere in your loop:

```
$template = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
echo "Template: " . $template;
```

Comment: Yes, I know about this, but the problem is that it works only when a page has a set template. The cool thing about the code I posted is that it will tell you if current page is using `front-page.php`, `index.php`, `single.php`, `page.php` or any other file. Your code displays template name only for pages with custom page template.

Comment: ah, sorry - my misunderstanding of your question.

Comment: @SimonBlackbourn It's help for my requirement. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't address all of the OP's question, but the code below is certainly more elegant than regular expressions and parsing the template file itself.

If you're on a Page that is using a Page Template, and you want to get the page template's Name (ie: the human-readable name that you defined in the comments at the top of your template PHP file), you can use this little nugget:

```
if ( is_page() && $current_template = get_page_template_slug( get_queried_object_id() ) ){
    $templates = wp_get_theme()->get_page_templates();
    $template_name = $templates[$current_template];
}
```

I wanted to get the template name because I was really sick of the silly-long-ass class names that the built-in WordPress `body_class` function creates when you're using a template. Luckily there's a filter hook at the very end of that function to let you append your own class names as well. Here's my filter. Hope someone finds it useful:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'gs_body_classes', 10, 2 );
function gs_body_classes( $classes, $class ){
    if ( is_page() && $current_template = get_page_template_slug( get_queried_object_id() ) ){
        $templates = wp_get_theme()->get_page_templates();
        $template_name = str_replace( " ", "-", strtolower( $templates[$current_template] ) );

        $classes[] = $template_name;
    }

    return $classes;
}
```

This filter will take whatever you named your page template, replace spaces with dashes and make everything lower case so it looks like all the other WordPress classes.

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with the `preg_match_all` line. Try this instead:

```
preg_match_all("/Template Name:(.*)\n/siU",$template_contents,$template_name);
```

Also, you can use `if (!is_admin()) { .... }` to run things on the frontend only.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, they don't solve the problem, but they kinda directed me into solutions. It turns out that WP, while generating templates list, is looking even into `functions.php` finds the `"/Template Name:(.*)\n/siU"` and thus treats the `functions.php` as template file. I think this is WP bug, it shouldn't even look at this file. The solution: move the file into subdirectory.

Comment: @chodorowicz: That's not a bug in WP, it's a bug in your function.

Comment: So basically WP forbids you to put string "Template Name:" (even in comment) in `functions.php` file. For me, personally, that's a bug, (small, but anyway) but that's the up to discussion, I suppose. I think you cannot say that the function itself is buggy.

Comment: WP doesn't forbid you to do anything. But WP also doesn't promise you that you can loop over a debug_backtrace() to find out what template file you're using. Just because you found it on a WP support forum doesn't mean it's officially supported code. As you may see, your function explicitly expludes footer.php. You may as well add another condition that excludes functions.php. BTW: your function doesn't look for `Template Name` within each of the files, your loop has ended long before that.

Comment: The problem wasn't with `debug_backtrace()` - I can remove all the code and just leave `preg_match_all("/Template Name...`, or even just `// Template Name:` and WP treats then `functions.php` as template file, but thanks for comments - this is such a unique problem that, as you say, it's not fair to say it's a bug. t31os solution is clean and solves the whole issue. Greets.

Answer (score 0):

Play along with:

```
echo '<ul><li>'.implode('</li><li>', str_replace(str_replace('\\', '/', ABSPATH).'wp-content/', '', array_slice(str_replace('\\', '/', get_included_files()), (array_search(str_replace('\\', '/', ABSPATH).'wp-includes/template-loader.php', str_replace('\\', '/', get_included_files())) + 1)))).'</li></ul>';
```

Written at:

[How do you find out which template page is serving the current page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37292/how-do-you-find-out-which-template-page-is-serving-the-current-page/)

if `admin-bar stuff` path is showing at the top, or any other file, change the filename `template-loader.php` in this line of code to: whatever filname you need to break from.

if you need this in the admin bar, **use the right priotity** (earliest) **to make shure no files are entered at the end** of this list. For example:

```
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'my_adminbar_template_monitor', -5);
```

priority `-5` make shure it loads first. The key is to render this line at the right moment.

It does not returning the "current" template-file, but all the current in use for the current page-load. **Maybe "cut out" with some logic from that idea**.

The `get_included_files()` "last" key is the last registered included file, propably the last template-file/ -part used in the footer by sidebar widget or something. Propably, cos mutiple included files does not re-register/ populates again in get_included_files().

Otherwise, *the intension must be clear to hack this problem*. **There is no way for a included file to report itself as included, until it has been included**. Then its propably to late to use the scenario.

Most of the "time" you *would* like:

```
$template = get_current_loaded_template();
if($template == 'single-product.php') add_filter('the_title' ....
if($template == 'format-gallery.php') add_action('post_thumbnail' ....
```

**But thats not possible** if the template is loaded outside Wordpress core method of `get_template_part`. Re-design your needs instead! Maybe `loop_start()`, `in_the_loop()` and `add_action('the_post')` has the solution you want, to alter data depending of template thats gonna load for each entry within a loop.

Answer (score -3):

```
global $post;
$templateName = get_page_template_slug( $post->ID );
//echo $templateName;
var_dump( $templateName );
```