# What is the best way to figure out which template file that a "pretty permalink" is using?

Tags: urls

I'm new at wordpress, so maybe this question is very basic, but I looked at Google and I searched for tutorials and I didn't find anything...

The question is simple. I have a "page", and this page is show as a friendly url. Example

http://www.example.com/seleccion/2011/03/24/abuso-sexual-el-secreto-y-la-verguenza-por-jose-andres-murillo/

How I coul find the php file where this "page" is render?

When you don't have friendly url, thats is easy : http://www.example.com/page_file.php?id=3&cat=8

but the friendly url hide all this information :(

Thanks in advance...

Comment: If a page is using pretty permalinks, then the request is always at `/index.php`. The file used to generate the page is going to be in your theme directory (e.g. `/wp-content/themes/twentyten`). I reworded your question to reflect this.

Comment: Are you looking for something like what was asked in: [Get name of the current template file](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10537/get-name-of-the-current-template-file/10565#10565)

Answer (score 2):

The pages are generated dynamically from a php template in the theme directory. All single posts would use single.php (or single-[post-type].php if the theme supports it).

Page templates would be page.php (or page-[page name].php or page-[id].php)

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but in WordPress that page is not related directly to a php file. If you are looking in the WordPress backend, you can go to either Posts or Pages and find that title, then hover over it and look in the status bar for the Post/Page ID, if that's what you're trying to find. Sorry not to be more help - maybe you can explain what you're looking for in a different way?

Comment: No, I need to transform this http://www.example.com/seleccion/2011/03/24/abuso-sexual-el-secreto-y-la-verguenza-por-jose-andres-murillo/ in this http://www.example.com/page_file.php?id=3&cat=8 so I could identify page_file.php