# Force WordPress to NOT display the manual excerpt

Tags: templates, archives, page-template, excerpt

I'm forced to use manual excerpts on a number of my posts to integrate them with a shortcode plugin. However, this is interfering with how they're being displayed on an archive page (using a page template). Is there a way to force WordPress to display an automated excerpt (ie, the first 80 words) on one page template only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize the `wp_trim_excerpt` filter. In your callback function that filters the the excerpt text, you can test for the presence of a certain template; then, if that template is being used, you can go ahead and alter the excerpt in any way that you see fit. In order to determine which template is being used, see this clever solution: [Get name of the current template file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10537/get-name-of-the-current-template-file). Let me know if this helps or if you need more.

Comment: Hi @tollmanz, I can definitely do this (or even just use the built-in WordPress function, [is_page_template()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#Is_a_Page_Template); I'm just not sure how to override the manual excerpt in the filter.

Comment: The `wp_trim_excerpt` is sent the manipulated text as the first parameter and the raw text as the second parameter. Are you comfortable working with filters? If so, look up `wp_trim_excerpt` in the core code. If not, I can help you along a little more.

Comment: Thanks @tollmanz, it turns out I can just use the `wp_trim_excerpt()` function to get the abbreviated excerpt.