# Strange Behavior of Page Template Dropdown

Tags: templates, debug

My wordpress is updated to latest version 3.4.1 and I noticed a strange function of it - in the Page attributes block page template dropdown has the value:

```
(.*)\n)siU",$template_contents,$template_name)
```

[image: screnshot]

Whay this is happening and how to get rid of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another similar thread that have been resolved now..
[Get name of the current template file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10537/get-name-of-the-current-template-file)
Take a look..

Comment: Yes, there was a solution - I had a string "template name" in file functions.php

Comment: Glad that worked !