# Is there a variable for a template parts name?

Tags: get-template-part

One you have called a template with `get_template_part()` (or `locate_template()`) is there a way to know what template you are in.

For example if you call `get_template_part('loop','archive');` from `archive.php`

and then are working in your loop-archive.php file.  is there a way to define a variable that has the name of the current template part.... so `$template = 'loop-archive'`.  better still, maybe in two parts so 'loop' and 'archive' but I can do that with some string splitting.

[Question #10537](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10537/get-name-of-the-current-template-file/64531#64531) seems sort of related but doesn't seem to cover template *parts*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a core global variable that returns the current context. However, you can construct your own, using contextual [template conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags). You can step through the conditional tags in the same order as WordPress core, by following [`wp-includes/template-loader.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/template-loader.php).

Simply wrap your output in a custom Theme function. [Here's how I do it](https://github.com/chipbennett/oenology/blob/master/functions/custom.php#L35) (note: I don't think I strictly follow template-loader.php):

```
function oenology_get_context() {

    $context = 'index';

    if ( is_home() ) {
        // Blog Posts Index
        $context = 'home';
        if ( is_front_page() ) {
            // Front Page
            $context = 'front-page';
        } 
    }else if ( is_date() ) {
        // Date Archive Index
        $context = 'date';
    } else if ( is_author() ) {
        // Author Archive Index
        $context = 'author';
    } else if ( is_category() ) {
        // Category Archive Index
        $context = 'category';
    } else if ( is_tag() ) {
        // Tag Archive Index
        $context = 'tag';
    } else if ( is_tax() ) {
        // Taxonomy Archive Index
        $context = 'taxonomy';
    } else if ( is_archive() ) {
        // Archive Index
        $context = 'archive';
    } else if ( is_search() ) {
        // Search Results Page
        $context = 'search';
    } else if ( is_404() ) {
        // Error 404 Page
        $context = '404';
    } else if ( is_attachment() ) {
        // Attachment Page
        $context = 'attachment';
    } else if ( is_single() ) {
        // Single Blog Post
        $context = 'single';
    } else if ( is_page() ) {
        // Static Page
        $context = 'page';
    }

    return $context;
}
```

Then, I just pass `oenology_get_context()` as a parameter, e.g.:

```
get_template_part( 'loop', oenology_get_context() );
```

I think something along these lines would be a good candidate for core, though I'm not sure the best way to implement. I'd love to submit a patch, though.

Comment: wow chip. that's very, very slick.  and your use case is exactly what i was intending.  as far as a patch, why wouldn't you just register this global right at the same time you are stepping through template loader?

Comment: Because I'm not sure if adding another global would be the "blessed" approach for core. Probably a function that returns context as a string would be better - but then, that would probably require a bit of a rewrite to `template-loader.php`.

Comment: Nice +1. Just one note: `index` would never match, as either `is_front_page()` or `is_home()` would trigger.

Comment: Another thing: `is_home()` should be first, as it gives back `front-page` even when the "latest post" setting is activated and no front-page is present. Just tested.

Comment: Agree with @kaiser. You can even use `is_home() && 'page'`, depending on the needs. For a more extensive information about Blog Posts vs Static Page in the Front Page, take a look at my own answer, here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208503/blog-posts-vs-static-page-conditional-statements. BTW, @Chip and @helgatheviking, it'd be better to use use a `switch` instead of so many `elseif` (it's more efficient ;-). Regards!

Answer (score 4):

bit of a facepalm, because the answer is in pure PHP

```
$path_parts = pathinfo(__FILE__);
//var_dump($path_parts); 
echo $path_parts['filename'];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source code of `get_template_part` function, you'll see:

```
function get_template_part( $slug, $name = null ) {
    do_action( "get_template_part_{$slug}", $slug, $name );

    $templates = array();
    if ( isset($name) )
        $templates[] = "{$slug}-{$name}.php";

    $templates[] = "{$slug}.php";

    locate_template($templates, true, false);
}
```

It creates an array of 2 template names: `{$slug}-{$name}.php` and `{$slug}.php` and use [`load_template`](http://look4wp.com/locate_template) to find the template file and include it (the 2nd parameter is `true`, which means include that file).

You can mimic this function to return the template file path instead of include it, like:

```
function my_get_template_part( $slug, $name = null, $include = false ) {
    do_action( "get_template_part_{$slug}", $slug, $name );

    $templates = array();
    if ( isset($name) )
        $templates[] = "{$slug}-{$name}.php";

    $templates[] = "{$slug}.php";

    return locate_template($templates, $include, false);
}
```

Usage:

```
// Don't load the template
$template = my_get_template_part( 'loop', 'archive', false );

// Or load the template
$template = my_get_template_part( 'loop', 'archive', true );

// Get the file name only
$template = basename( $template );

// Without .php extension
$template = substr( $template, 0, -4 );
```

You can play more with `$template` to get what you want.

Comment: that's pretty neat! +1 for sure, but i needed to know the $template info inside the loop-arhive.php template (to follow your example)

Comment: You can use a global variable which is set in `archive.php`, and reuse it in `loop-archive.php`

Answer (score 2):

### List all conditionals that are `true`

As all `is_*()` functions have their equivalent in a query variable (the functions are just wrappers), you can access them also another way: Get simply all that are `true`.

I wrote a ticket on [**core/trac**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19041) that adds a function to list them all.

In the meanwhile you can use both listed functions as helper plugins that show you on which request which conditional is available. It will print a `var_dump()` below the footer (both admin & public) at the `shutdown` hook.

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: (#62232) »kaiser« List all conditionals that are true */
function get_conditionals()
{ 
    global $wp_query; 

    foreach ( get_object_vars( $wp_query ) as $is_key => $is_value ) 
    { 
            if ( $is_value && preg_match( "/is_/", $is_key ) ) 
                    $conditionals[] = $is_key; 
    } 

    return var_dump( $conditionals );
} 
add_action( 'shutdown', 'get_conditionals' );
```

This way you can simply loop through them.

@scribu added his own function to the ticket (an interesting solution too).

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: (#62232) »scribu« List all conditionals that are true */
function get_query_flags( $wp_query = null ) {
    if ( !$wp_query )
        $wp_query = $GLOBALS['wp_query'];

    $flags = array();

    foreach ( get_object_vars( $wp_query ) as $key => $val ) {
        if ( 'is_' == substr( $key, 0, 3 ) && $val )
            $flags[] = substr( $key, 3 );
    }

    return var_dump( $flags );
}
add_action( 'shutdown', 'get_query_flags' );
```

### Performance

I ran a performance test on each function in the middle of a template using `timer_start/*_stop();`. TO be fair, I renamed all functions to a one character name `a/b/c()`.

As you can see, Chips hard coded function is fastest, then goes mine and last is in this case scribus.

[image]

### Update

If you know me, then you know my love for iterators for their elegance, clearness and their ability to hold only a single item in memory instead of of copy of a whole array while looping. So here's a quick custom class that extends a `\FilterIterator`, therefore needing only a single method reworked.

```
<?php

namespace WPSE;

class ConditionalsFilter extends \FilterIterator
{
    /**
     * Accepts properties that start with `is_` and have a positive boolean value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function accept()
    {
        return 0 === strncasecmp( $this->key(), 'is_', 3 )
            and filter_var(
                $this->current(),
                FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN,
                FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE
            );
    }
}
```

It can be used quite easily. The `$it->current()` holds the value, while `$it->key()` returns the conditional/property name.

```
$cond = new WPSE\ConditionalsFilter( new \ArrayIterator(
    get_object_vars( $GLOBALS['wp_query'] )
) );
foreach ( $cond as $c )
{
    var_dump(
        $cond->key(),
        $cond->current()
    );
}
```

Comment: Well that is very clever.  Thanks!  I'll have to re-visit this when I get done with some of the other things I am working.  Also, it is really hard to remember to capitalize!  Bad habits are tough to break.

Comment: @kaiser - Why call the function at `shutdown` and not earlier in the process? Secondly, the function outputs the result as `array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "is_home" [1]=> string(13) "is_posts_page" }`. Have I understood it correctly that `is_home` is the parent `conditional` and it encapsulates `is_posts_page`? If yes, I assume it is safe to perform a conditional check limited to just `is_home` rather than `is_home && `is_posts_page`?