# function to include is_home, is_archive, is_category, is_author etc in one function?

Tags: functions

I'd like a way to target only blog-area pages for specific formatting.

So far,

```
<?php if (is_home() || is_single() || is_category() || is_archive() ) { ?>
```

works okay, but is there a way to combine all of those into one single function to shorten it up a bit? so maybe in the functions it would set is_blog() to equal those four (or however many I want).

Seems a bit simple and probably is.... I just dont know what to search for to find information on this. Thanks!!

Comment: Hi there ... `is_archive` should cover [is_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_archive) ... what type of formating are you trying to do?  as its probably better to do this inside The Loop

Comment: How can we use is_blog() function in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you described:

```
function is_blog()
{
    return ( is_home() || is_single() || is_category() || is_archive() );
}
```

And then just call the is_blog() function whenever needed.

I also found this, which looks like a more specific way to do the same thing https://gist.github.com/1189639

Answer (score 0):

All the `is_*()` [»Conditional Tags«](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) are wrappers for their `is_*` pendants in the global `$wp_query` object. They all reflect parts of the [»Template Hierarchy«](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png) which determines which file should be loaded (if present) to display the request.

To make it short here're the most general:

- `is_archive()` covers all Tag, Taxonomy, Category, Post Type (Post/Page/Attachments/links/Custom Post Type, etc.) archive pages (there's also `is_post_type_archive()` to lock those out).
- `is_home()` and `is_front_page()` are basically the same, with the difference, that they distinguish the display setting for the front page: Latest posts & static front page.
- `is_singular()` catches all "single" views, like a page, an attachment, a post, etc.
- `is_search()` covers search *result* pages
- `is_404()` catches everything ... that wasn't catched

So based on this list, you should be able to wrape up what you need - depending what "blog area pages" are for you.

---

As a little helper, you can use the functions from [this answer that lists all conditionals that are `true` on a request](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/64527/385). This should help you getting around it pretty quick.

Just upload it as a plugin. Deactivate it when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

bit more completed with PHP function would possible include strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "blog")

final solution:

```
    function is_blog()
    {
        return ( is_home() || is_single() || is_category() || is_archive() || strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "blog") );
    }
```