# Detect archive and category page

Tags: blog

I would like to detect following pages:

`http://192.168.1.100/wordpress/?m=201311` - blog archive

`http://192.168.1.100/wordpress/?cat=1` - blog category

For example, post type I can easly detect with:

> $page_id = get_queried_object_id();
>
> if (get_post_type( $page_id ) != 'slideshow')

How about the above pages ? I mean any category or archive page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) for this: [`is_archive()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_archive) and [`is_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category) respectively. For a custom post type archives you could use [`is_post_type_archive()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive). There are many conditional tags available, see above linked codex page. To determine the blog archive you have to additionally check for the post type `post`, take a look at [this question and the answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/68097/22534) for more useful information.