# How can I add "posted by 'author'" to each post?

Tags: author

With a multi-user blog, how can I add a *posted by Some Author* line, or something similar, at the top of each post, as in [this blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com/)?  I assumed this should be something very basic, and there should be a setting for it, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plug-in might use `the_content` filter to append / prepend this, but if you're a theme author or otherwise are able to edit the the theme templates directly.

In this case you want to edit your theme's `single.php`. (You can always check which template file is being used by a particular page using this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/10565/9364).

`single.php` is used for single posts, and other post types if they do not have their own template (you see how WordPress decides what template to use here).

In `single.php` you should find something like

```
 <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
```

Which includes another file depending on the post's format. For a normal post, this will be `content.php`. (Please note this may vary by theme - the upshot is that you want to find where it calls `the_content()`) - `the_content()` is what displays the post content.

Below that you want to add something like:

```
the_author();
```

(see [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author)). Check the TwentyTwelve theme for more 'involved' example.

Comment: I posted the solution that solves this in my case, but this answer is more general (not twenty-twelve-specific) so I'll accept this one.

Answer (score 2):

With the twenty-twelve theme, the following is in `style.css`:

```
.single-author .entry-meta .by-author {
    display: none;
}
```

This was the source of the problem and it needed to be commented out.

Comment: Yep, worked for me. Just in case anyone else has trouble finding it: Appearance > Editor > Select Stylesheet (style.css) from the right hand menu.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, but it sounds like what you want is [`the_author`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author).

The Codex page for that function has an example of what you want, I think:

```
<p>This post was written by <?php the_author(); ?></p>
```

You will have to edit that into one or more of your theme templates but without having the code for the theme I can't say where.