# Is there a way to retrieve the calling template part?

Tags: theme-development, get-template-part

If I include a template part within header.php like this:

```
    <?php get_template_part('templates/social-icons'); ?>
```

Is there a way to retrieve the template name `header.php` within this template part? i.e the name of the template which is including `social-icons.php`?

So in social-icons.php I want to retrieve the name 'headers.php' dynamically so that I can include social-icons.php elsewhere and react to the name of the calling template.

perhaps something using PHP's `get_included_files()` or `pathinfo()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/10565/500), I went with:

```
$template_tree = mytheme_get_template_tree();
$total = count($template_tree); //count the elements in the array
end($template_tree); //set the pointer to the end of the array
$immediate_parent = basename(prev($template_tree)); //get the filename of the penultimate element
```

Then in a plugin / functions.php

```
function mytheme_get_template_tree()
{
    $included_files = get_included_files();
    $stylesheet_dir = str_replace( '\\', '/', get_stylesheet_directory() );
    $template_dir   = str_replace( '\\', '/', get_template_directory() );

    foreach ( $included_files as $key => $path ) {

        $path = str_replace( '\\', '/', $path );

        if ( FALSE === strpos( $path, $stylesheet_dir ) && FALSE === strpos( $path, $template_dir ) ) {
            unset( $included_files[ $key ] );
        }
    }

    return $included_files;

}
```

Am still interested to hear about alternative approaches though!